# Compilation failure: android support-v4 + maven

Tags: android, maven, android-support-library

I am compiling my android project with maven. I have used [maven android sdk deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) to install android sdk to local repository.
Everything was working fine until I added some notification code. I still can launch my app from eclipse, but maven build gives following errors:

```
[ERROR] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method create(com.my.example.SomeService)
[ERROR] location: class android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder
[ERROR] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : method build()
[ERROR] location: class android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder
```

Here is support-v4 dependency from my pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    <version>21.0.0-rc1</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone help pls?

**Update**

The error occuring in the project (lets call it A) that depends on several library projects (say B, C and D) each of which depends on support-v4 library. B, C and D are build with maven too and have same *support-v4:aar:21.0.0-rc1* dependency as project A. Can this cause such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved!
The reason was that one of the dependencies (referenced as B, C and D in the question) of the main project had an old version of support-v4 as a dependency. Once it's dependency was updated the build succceeded.

Hope it will help someone.

Comment: Hello @aleks,
I have the same problem. I'm sorry I didn't understand the answer, would you please explain more? The current version for support-v4 on my project is <version>r7</version> Should I update this? If yes what is the latest version, if not, what should I do?